# Convert csv file into table in KDB+/q

Tags: csv, kdb

How to convert a csv file data and store into table in kdb+/q

I tried to read the file like

```
csvData: read0 `path/to/your/csvfile.csv
table: flip csvData 0: enlist ","
```

But the above shows type error in the second line

```
table: flip csvData 0: enlist ","
```

Is there any alternate to get the csv data and store in a table when the schema/meta of the columns in the csv is not known.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this reference for [loading csv files using q](https://code.kx.com/q/learn/tour/csvs/)

Once you've got the data in-memory, you can persist to disk in a number of ways depending on your use case.

For example, you can save the table:

- [binary](https://code.kx.com/q/database/object/)
- [splayed](https://code.kx.com/q/kb/splayed-tables/)
- [partitioned](https://code.kx.com/q/kb/partition/)

If you don't know the number of columns ahead of time, you could read the first line (assuming it's a comma-seperated header) as follows:

```
q)show header:`$"," vs first "\n" vs read1 `:sample.csv
`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5

q)show data:(count[header]#"*";enlist csv) 0: `:sample.csv
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
------------------------
,"1" ,"2" ,"3" ,"4" ,"5"
```

Few notes/limitations, here with this approach:

1. It might be more efficient to use [read1](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/read1/) and only read the first N bytes, until the first newline to capture the header. Useful on very large csv files.
2. The data in the example above is all read in as strings, which may not be optimal and appropriate typing should be considered after reviewing the data.

You could take this a step further and map the specific column names to certain types and apply those to the data during/after loading, then upsert the data into an existing table schema.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try `csvguess.q` which is designed for what you ask.

https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/csvguess.q